# Vectorizing a function involving a while loop or if-clause in a loop (Matlab)

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, conditional-statements, vectorization

Let's say I have a function that can compute one output from one input, e.g.

```
function y = sqrt_newton(x)
    y = x ./ 2;
    yo = y;
    y = 0.5.*(y + x ./ y);
    while abs(y - yo) > eps * abs(y)
        yo = y;
        y = 0.5.*(y + x ./ y);
    end
end
```

I'd like to be able to apply this function to a vector input say `sqrt_newton(2:9)` like with built-in functions. What is the best way to achieve this with a condition at the beginning of the loop or some if-clause inside? I'd like to avoid writing an extra function as a wrapper just to loop through the input vector, if possible at all.

**My current cumbersome solution**

What I do up until now is:

- I have to expand first the inputs to the same size (using finargsz from the finance toolbox, but if you know of another core function that does the same, that would be great)
- record the shape using `size`
- `deal` the inputs
- loop thru all the input elements
- `reshape` the output

It seems that the `numel` function alleviates the need of all this heavy lifting but extra comments would be most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's always [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html). You can keep the code you have, putting it into an inner function.

```
function y = sqrt_newton(z)

    y = arrayfun(@inner, z);

    function y= inner(x)
        y = x ./ 2;
        yo = y;
        y = 0.5.*(y + x ./ y);
        while abs(y - yo) > eps * abs(y)
            yo = y;
            y = 0.5.*(y + x ./ y);
        end
    end
end
```

**Edit:** The above solution has the advantage of being trivial to implement after you have it working with a 1x1 input, but the loops in the other answers are way faster for large inputs. For example, on my computer, the code

```
tic; sqrt_newton(rand(500)); toc
```

runs in `~1.24 seconds` with my code, `0.06 seconds` with @Ramashalanka's code, and `0.28 seconds` with @GuntherStruyf's code.

Comment: Well, I like your solution as it has a minimal overhead with respect to the original function. Too bad it's so sluggish.

Answer (score 2):

I think in general you'll have to use a loop, because of the unknown character of the operation of the function. In case it's a linear operation, vectorization is possible.

For your example I'd use the following:

```
function y = sqrt_newton(x)
    y = x ./ 2;
    yo = y;
    y = 0.5.*(y + x ./ y);
    for i=1:numel(x)
        while abs(y(i) - yo(i)) > eps * abs(y(i))
            yo(i) = y(i);
            y(i) = 0.5*(y(i) + x(i) / y(i));
        end
    end
end
```

I use numel, instead of size, so it can handle any array I throw at it

Comment: In fact, I use a similar solution but I was expecting some other way to do it neatly. See my extra comment under the question.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you *could* vectorize it as follows (with `any`):

```
function y = sqrt_newton(x)
    y = x / 2;
    yo = y;
    y = 0.5*(y + x ./ y);
    while any(abs(y - yo) > eps * abs(y))
        yo = y;
        y = 0.5*(y + x ./ y);
    end
end
```

Then you get:

```
>> sqrt_newton(2:9)
ans =
    1.4142    1.7321    2.0000    2.2361    2.4495    2.6458    2.8284    3.0000

>> ans.^2-(2:9)
ans =
   1.0e-14 *
   -0.0444   -0.0444         0    0.0888   -0.0888    0.0888   -0.1776         0
```

as expected. However, I wouldn't recommend it, since you're doing unnecessary operations on elements that have already converged. I'd just use a `for` loop over `x` at the start of the function:

```
function yall = sqrt_newton(xall)
yall = zeros(size(xall));
for xn=1:numel(xall)
    x = xall(xn);
    y = x / 2;
    yo = y;
    y = 0.5*(y + x ./ y);
    while abs(y - yo) > eps * abs(y)
        yo = y;
        y = 0.5*(y + x ./ y);
    end
    yall(xn)=y;
end
end
```

Set the size `yall` at the start to avoid it increasing in size throughout the loop.